# error: Non-nullable instance field 'result' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a flutter beginner dev and I am currently developing a BMI Calculator app with flutter and Dart. Actually in my code I am facing the following errors.

- `error: Non-nullable instance field 'result' must be initialized at [bmi_app] lib\calresult.dart:16)`
- `error: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type. (body_might_complete_normally at [bmi_app] lib\calresult.dart:16)`

Here is my main.dart file:

```
import 'package:bmi_app/calresult.dart';
import 'package:bmi_app/resultscreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

enum Gender {
  male,
  female,
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF24232F),
        accentColor: Color(0XFF1F1E29),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF2F2E3A),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: InputScreen()
    )
  );
}

class InputScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InputScreenState createState() => _InputScreenState();
}

class _InputScreenState extends State<InputScreen> {
  Color inactiveColor = Color(0xFF24232F);
  Color activeColor = Colors.blueGrey;
  Gender selectedGender = Gender.values.single;

  int height = 100;
  int weight = 50;
  int age = 15;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
              "BMI Calculator"
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.male;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                          color: selectedGender == Gender.male
                              ? activeColor
                              : inactiveColor
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.male,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 45.0,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Male",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.female;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                          color: selectedGender == Gender.female
                              ? activeColor
                              : inactiveColor
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.female,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 45.0,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Female",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  color: inactiveColor
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "HEIGHT",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                          height.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          )
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "cm",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SliderTheme(data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                    activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                    overlayColor: Color(0x291DE9B6),
                    inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
                    thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(
                        enabledThumbRadius: 16.0
                    ),
                    overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(
                        overlayRadius: 30.0
                    ),
                    thumbColor: Color(0xFF1DE9B6),
                  ),
                      child: Slider(
                        value: height.toDouble(),
                        min: 50.0,
                        max: 300.0,
                        onChanged: (double v){
                          setState(() {
                            height = v.round();
                          });
                        },
                      )
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: 10.0
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10.0
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                        color: inactiveColor
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Weight",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 8.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          weight.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 8.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.add,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                onPressed: (){
                                  setState(() {
                                    weight++;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10.0
                            ),
                              CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.remove,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: (){
                                    setState(() {
                                      if(weight>10){
                                        weight--;
                                      }
                                    }
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: 10.0
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10.0
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                        color: selectedGender == Gender.female
                            ? activeColor
                            : inactiveColor
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                        Text(
                        "Age",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                        age.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        )
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8.0,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){
                          setState(() {
                            age++;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                        width: 10.0
                    ),
                    CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.remove,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: (){
                          setState(() {
                            if(age>5){
                              age--;
                            }
                          }
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
              ],
            )
        ],
      ),
    ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: 10.0
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 10.0
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 80.0,
              color: Color(0xFF1DE9B6),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Calculate BMI",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onTap: (){
              navigateToResultScreen(12.0);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void navigateToResultScreen(double result){
    CalculateResult obj = CalculateResult(weight, height);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResultScreen(obj.calculateResult(),obj.msg, obj.getDescription())));
  }
}
```

In addition to that there are two other files:

- resultscreen.dart:

  ```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class ResultScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      String result;
      String msg;
      String des;
      ResultScreen(this.result, this.msg, this.des);

      @override
      _ResultScreenState createState() => _ResultScreenState();
    }

    class _ResultScreenState extends State<ResultScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF2F2E3A),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("BMI Results"),
          ),
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Text("Your Results",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 10.0
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 10.0
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                      color: Color(0xFF2F2E3A)
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        widget.result,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          fontSize: 26.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget.msg,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.green,
                          fontSize: 26.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget.des,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 26.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              bottom: 10.0
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            color: Color(0xFF1DE9B6),
                            child: Text(
                              "Recalculate...",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                )
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  ```

  - And calresult.dart:

import 'dart:math';

```
class CalculateResult{
  CalculateResult(this.weight, this.height);
  final int height;
  final int weight;
  double result;
  String msg = "Normal";

  String calculateResult(){
    result = weight / pow(height/100, 2);
    return result.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }

  String getDescription(){
    if(result > 25){
      msg = "Over weight";
      return "You have a higher weight than normal. Try to lose somme through any activity you like!";
    }
    else if(result > 18.5){
      msg = "Normal";
      return "You have a normal weight. Keep it!";
    }
    else if(result < 18.5){
      msg = "Under Weight";
      return "Your weight is less than normal weight. You need to get some. Make sure to have a correct and balanced diet. ";
    }
  }
}
```

Hope to get some helpful tips from the community to solve these errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues on your `calresult.dart` file.

First, There is a null-nullable instance called result. So, we need to initialize it or we could use `late keyword` for the result variable. By declaring a non-nullable `late` variable, we promise that it will be non-null at runtime, and Dart helps us with some compile-time guarantees.

And next issue is, you need to return `String` in the getDescription() method. Because its return type is String.

calresult.dart file (Fixed one) -

```
class CalculateResult{
  
  final int height;
  final int weight;
  late double result;
  String msg = "Normal";
  
  CalculateResult(this.weight, this.height);

  String calculateResult(){
    result = weight / pow(height/100, 2);
    return result.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }

  String getDescription(){
    if(result > 25){
      msg = "Over weight";
      return "You have a higher weight than normal. Try to lose somme through any activity you like!";
    }
    else if(result > 18.5){
      msg = "Normal";
      return "You have a normal weight. Keep it!";
    }
    else if(result < 18.5){
      msg = "Under Weight";
      return "Your weight is less than normal weight. You need to get some. Make sure to have a correct and balanced diet. ";
    }
    
    return "need to return string";
  }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks very much @Yohan, This really solved the errors which occured.

Answer (score 0):

`String getDescription()` means it have to return `String`, but there's a case return `null`.